# Expected value of init in AMediaDrm_getKeyRequest for PlayReady

Tags: android, android-ndk, drm, playready

Context:

I want to decrypt EME content of type video/mp4 on Android. I opened a `MediaDrm` instance using PlayReady UUID. `AMediaDrmKeyType` is `KEY_TYPE_STREAMING`.

I am unable to obtain a key request from `AMediaDrm_getKeyRequest`. I suspect the init data I provide is incorrect, because it's the only parameter I'm not certain about.

The only information I can find is in the [library's header](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/master/media/ndk/include/media/NdkMediaDrm.h) and not very specific:

```
/*
* init container-specific data, its meaning is interpreted based on the mime type
* provided in the mimeType parameter.  It could contain, for example, the content
* ID, key ID or other data obtained from the content metadata that is required in
* generating the key request. init may be null when keyType is KEY_TYPE_RELEASE.
*/

media_status_t AMediaDrm_getKeyRequest(AMediaDrm *, const AMediaDrmScope *scope,
    const uint8_t *init, size_t initSize, const char *mimeType, AMediaDrmKeyType keyType,
    const AMediaDrmKeyValue *optionalParameters, size_t numOptionalParameters,
    const uint8_t **keyRequest, size_t *keyRequestSize);
```

With other DRM libraries, usually the key request API requires a PlayReady PSSH box. I've tried this with `AMediaDrm_getKeyRequest()` but I only get a generic error -10000.

I've also tried the content ID or key ID, as suggested by the documentation, to no avail.

What is the expected init data for the call to AMediaDrm_getKeyRequest() for PlayReady content?

Comment: I am guessing your device does actually support PlayReady DRM  if you are able to create the MediaDRM instance, even though Widevine is the usual default DRM on Android and regular Android device are not required to support PlayReady by default (Android TV is I think)  but are you able to share what device type it is and how PlayReady is included on it, i.e. at OEM or via some other way?

Comment: The only device I'm allowed to share this is happening on is an Nvidia Shield. On the target device, PlayReady is provided by OEM.

Comment: Its hard to find open sharable examples of this case as Widevine is much more common on Android, but if you look at this opensoure project it has an example call showing how they set init from the PSSH: https://github.com/peak3d/inputstream.adaptive/blob/master/wvdecrypter/wvdecrypter_android.cpp

Comment: I was able to make it work by sending the complete PlayReady PSSH as obtained by the server.